# Processes PPID changed to 1 after closing parent shell

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, process

Opening a new terminal and typing the command `firefox&` inside, `ps -l` gives :

```
4 R  1000 23132 23104 99  80   0 - 2177945 -    pts/27   00:00:07 firefox
```

If the shell is closed with the command `exit`, the firefox child process stays open !

Was it always the case ? Isn't firefox supposed to be closing as well ? Is there something new in a recent kernel or something i'm missing ?

The result of `ps -el|grep firefox` is then :

```
4 S  1000 23132     1 14  80   0 - 2233312 poll_s ?      00:00:21 firefox
```

The PPID has been changed to 1.

What is responsible for this PPID change to 1 ?

EDIT : Oh I've just realised that closing the terminal and closing the shell have very different results : closing the terminal does close all the child processes, but not when the shell is closed with the exit command... No idea why. (Closing terminal is sending SIGTERM to all child processes ? But closing shell is leaving orphans ?)

Comment: parent process died, so it changes PPID to the closest reaper process. So kernel will maintain a strict process tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there something new in a recent kernel or something I'm missing?

No, if a process exits, its children keep running, their parent process just gets changed to `init` (PID 1). Or some other, system-dependent process, look up e.g. "subreapers" on Linux.

That's always been the case, it's what allows `nohup` to work usefully, as well the aged process of turning a process into a daemon by forking twice, calling `setsid()` and exiting the parent processes.

Closing a terminal session might send `SIGHUP` to the remaining processes there, but they're free to ignore it (and that's what `nohup` does). Also, `systemd` can be configured to kill any lingering processes when a terminal login session exits, but you're probably running `firefox` within X from a terminal emulator, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks, but if firefox is launched without the &, and the terminal is closed, firefox will close as well. What is happening there ? SIGTERM for terminal and all child processes ?

Comment: Same if the process is stopped by for example SIGTSTP (ctrl + z) exiting is also closing it, what is happening really ? Where is the official doc about this behavior ?

Comment: @bobdylan, I can never remember the exact details of the signals sent when a terminal closes (and what part of the system sends them to what processes), you'll have to ask another question about that.

Comment: I edited my initial message, I was assuming that closing terminal and closing shell had the same effect. They do not. Still unclear for me though...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476210/difference-between-closing-terminal-and-closing-shell-on-child-processes